# How to make to work pentaho custom component?

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, custom-component, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to create a new Custom Component in pentaho. It is just a menu for every dashboard that I need to use, with some buttons and a text input.

I have in my solutions/system/pentaho-cdf-dd/resources/custom/components my ControlComponent folder, with component.xml and control-implementation.js. I have too in amd-components, the same folder but with ControlComponent.js.

In CDE, I can use it, but every time I run my dashboard, come the error from javascript.

```
define(['cdf/components/BaseComponent', 'cdf/lib/jquery'], 

function(BaseComponent, $) {
    return BaseComponent.extend({
        update: function() {
            if(this.htmlObject){
                var ph = $("#" + this.htmlObject);
            } else{
                var ph = $("<div id='ControlDefault'></div>").appendTo("body");
            }


            var content = '<div id="Control" class="row clearfix">'+
                 '<div class="col-xs-6-last">'+
                     '<div>'+
                         '<div class="row clearfix">'+
                             '<div class="col-xs-1">'+
                                 '<div id="Left" title="left">'+
                                  + 
                                 '</div>'+
                               '</div>'+                      
                           '</div>'+
                         '</div>'+
                       '</div>'+    
                     '</div>';
            ph.append(content);            
        }
    });
});
```

The error is:

```
require.js:8 Uncaught Error: Script error for: 
cde/components/ControlComponent
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at C (require.js:8)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:30)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought I found an error with a double plus sign in the middle of your `content` string concatenation, but apart from generating a `NaN` in the middle of your HTML, it doesn't generate an error... It's worth it to correct it nonetheless :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't answer before, but it was that typo fail.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the  tag in component.xml is named controlComponent to match your js file name.  RequireJS uses the IName tag value to reference the js file name instead of the Code tag src attribute.

Also, the Implementation tag needs attribute supportsAMD="true".